# Drop row with NaN value in a Dataframe, only after the first non NaN Value

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with different columns. Some columns might start with a serie of NaN value before the real values starts. However, after the first non NaN value in each columns, some NaN value can also appear. For example :

```
              A    B    C
2021-08-31  1.0  NaN  5.0
2021-09-01  2.0  NaN  NaN
2021-09-02  4.0  3.0  NaN
2021-09-03  NaN  7.0  5.0
2021-09-06  2.0  5.0  5.0
2021-09-07  9.0  NaN  5.0
2021-09-08  4.0  5.0  NaN
```

I would like to remove all the line where there is a NaN value **but only after the first non NaN value in the column**. Said differently, the NaN values before the first non NaN value are not taken into account in the removal process.

So the previous example, would look something like this :

```
              A    B    C
2021-08-31  1.0  NaN  5.0
2021-09-06  2.0  5.0  5.0
```

I started looking for a solution using the list of 'first_valid_date' and then removing with conditions on the index being after the first_valid_date of the column plus the value being NaN but I have problem with the removal of value with 2 conditions (NaN and index) :

`df.drop(df[df.isna().any(axis=1) & df.index > mydateindex].index)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the correct way to do it :

```
df.loc[~(df.fillna(method='ffill').notna() & ~df.notna()).max(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this with `loc` and `isna` with `notna`, and `shift`:

```
>>> df.loc[(~(df.shift().notna() & df.isna() & df.shift(-1).notna())).all(1)]
              A    B
2021-08-31  1.0  NaN
2021-09-01  2.0  NaN
2021-09-02  4.0  3.0
2021-09-06  2.0  5.0
2021-09-08  4.0  5.0
>>>
```

Comment: Thx, it almost work except it doesn't remove lines before all columns have their first_valide_date (i will change my example to make it clearer)

Comment: Thx for your help, you're right on this example. I thought I understood the reason why it doesn't work, so i put a more simple example. Obviously I did not understaood well enough ;). I will modify the post with one i'm sure doesn't work.

Comment: @FredDujardin Well I am almost 100% sure that this works for everything... Please remember to select this answer if it helps :)

Comment: with your code, the result keep line : '2021-09-01',  '2021-09-02' and '2021-09-08', all with NaN on column C after the first valide date

Comment: It looks like there are pb with consecutive NaN after first valid date and NaN in last row